# How can we open a Popper when page load the first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, ref, popper.js

With https://material-ui.com/components/popper/ React, material-ui,
[image]
I want to show the Popper just after the page loaded, without clicking on the button.

```
import React from 'react'
import Popper from '@material-ui/core/Popper'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade'
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper'

export default function PositionedPopper() {
  const elRef = React.useRef(null)

  return (
    <div>
      <Popper open={true} anchorEl={elRef.current} placement={'left'} transition>
        {({ TransitionProps }) => (
          <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
            <Paper>
              <Typography>The content of the Popper.</Typography>
            </Paper>
          </Fade>
        )}
      </Popper>
      <Button ref={elRef}>left</Button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This code shows the popper on the top left on the screen because onInit, `anchorEl` is Null

How can we set `anchorEl` when the component loads the first time?

Comment: What does first time mean? Like first time the user goes to any page, the first time they go to the site this session, the first time they ever visit the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Init the `open status` with **useEffect** would work

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  setOpen(true);
}, []);

<Popper
  open={open}
  ...
/>
```

Full code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import Popper from "@material-ui/core/Popper";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Fade from "@material-ui/core/Fade";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

export default function PositionedPopper() {
  const elRef = useRef(null);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setOpen(true);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Popper
        open={open}
        anchorEl={elRef.current}
        placement={"left"}
        transition
      >
        {({ TransitionProps }) => (
          <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
            <Paper>
              <Typography>The content of the Popper.</Typography>
            </Paper>
          </Fade>
        )}
      </Popper>
      <Button ref={elRef}>left</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit wizardly-banach-46fmm]

Answer (score 2):

use state instead of ref

```
export default function App(){
   const [el, setEl] = useState(null);
   const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
   return (
     <div>
        <button ref={setEl} onClick={()=> setOpen(true)}></button>
        <Popper open={el != null && open} anchorEl={el}>
           ....
        </Popper>
     </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but typeScript is not accepting it.. https://snipboard.io/VRCn0P.jpg